# Wrong result of nginx rewrite in ngix.conf

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I write a rewrite segment in nginx for get the content of http://list.example.com:89/findcontent.action?id=6 while I visit http://www.example.com/list/findcontent.action?id=6 and get the content of http://www.example.com:81 while I visit http://www.example.com. 
The nginx.conf list below and can work fine when I visit www.example.com. But when I visit www.example.com/list/findcontent.action?id=6 I get the 404 error from http://list.example.com:89/list/findcontent.action?id=6. It's mean the rewrite don't work.
Could any one help me to get the right config? Thanks.

```
server {
            listen  80; 
            listen  443 ssl; 
            server_name  www.example.com;
            keepalive_timeout   70;
            ssl_certificate     cert\www.example.com_public.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key  cert\www.example.com.key;
            ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            charset utf-8;
            access_log  logs/example_com.host.access.log;
            location  /list {
            rewrite ^/list '' break;
            proxy_pass   http://list.example.com:89/;
            }
            location  / {
            proxy_pass   http://www.example.com:81;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to rewrite `/list/findcontent.action?id=6` to `/findcontent.action?id=6`, your `rewrite` statement is incomplete. You are missing a capture.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/list(.*)$ $1 break;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

---

You can achieve a similar function using just the `location` and `proxy_pass` directives.

For example:

```
location /list/ {
    proxy_pass   http://list.example.com:89/;
}
```

Note the trailing `/` on both the `location` and `proxy_pass` values. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: Thanks for help. While I follow the sugguest, I get 404 error like this:
>
>HTTP Status 404 - /findcontent.action
>type Status report
>
>message /findcontent.action
>
>description The requested resource is not available.
>
>Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
>
>
>
Both the two method. Is there something wrong or miss?